# Squares in chessboard that must not lie in the same row or same column

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> In how many ways is it possible to choose a white square
>   and black square on a chessboard so that the squares 
>   must not lie in the same row or same column?

$a.)\ 56 \\
b.)\ 896 \\
c.)\ 60 \\
\color{green}{d.)\ 786} $

I did $\dbinom{64}{2}-\dbinom{32}{1} \dbinom{32}{1} =992$

But its none of the options .

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: 32*32 is the number of ways to choose a white square and a black square since there are 32 white squares and 32 black squares. Now how many ways are there to choose a white square and black square in the same row/column?

Answer (score 5):

A chessboard contains $32$ white squares, so you have $32$ possible choices for the white square. Now in the same column or row of this square lie $8$ black square which you can't choose, leaving $32 - 8 = 24$ possible black squares to choose from. This yields a total of $32 \cdot 24 = 768$ possible choices.

Comment: But in the corner lines there are $7$ black squares .

Comment: @RK Count again. Recall that we consider rows and columns intersecting in white

Comment: See this http://prntscr.com/8eid4a

Comment: But you choose a white square first, therefore you can't have this particular combination of a row and a column. Note that if you choose a white square, you have $4$ black squares in the same row and $4$ black squares in the same column as the white square.